# Load params.php file in codeception is not working

Tags: php, integration-testing, codeception

contents of codeception.yml

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - REST:
        depends: PhpBrowser
        url : http://localhost
        part: Json

params:
    - params.php
```

my php file is:

```
<?php

return [
   "param1" => "some value",
   "param2" => "second value",
];
```

and when run this line in my test case I do not get the params

```
print_r( \Codeception\Configuration::config() );
```

output of above line:

```
(
    [bootstrap] => 
    [coverage] => Array
        (
        )

    [params] => Array
        (
        )

    [gherkin] => Array
        (
        )
)
```